# Find historical maximums in time series

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to identify historical maximum records from time-series data. I need to only identify maximum records as they pertain to data up to that point, not for the whole vector.

An example:

```
set.seed(431)
df <- data.frame(time = c(1:10), value = runif(10, 1, 10))

df
   time    value
1     1 7.758703
2     2 6.262849
3     3 8.281712
4     4 8.243617
5     5 6.781752
6     6 2.078103
7     7 4.455353
8     8 1.339119
9     9 3.635554
10   10 9.084619
```

What I want to do is produce the vector that identifies the following record high numbers moving forward in time:

```
   time    value record
1     1 7.758703    yes
2     2 6.262849     no
3     3 8.281712    yes
4     4 8.243617     no
5     5 6.781752     no
6     6 2.078103     no
7     7 4.455353     no
8     8 1.339119     no
9     9 3.635554     no
10   10 9.084619    yes
```

The value at time 1 is a record because no values exist prior to that, therefor it is maximum. The item at time 3 is a record because its higher than that at time 1. The value at time 10 is a record because its higher than that at time 3.

All I have been able to do is test the max value for the whole vector (i.e identify the value at time 10), rather than the vector up to the time value being considered. I was trying to mutate through dplyr but it wouldn't work. Then I looked at writing a for loop, which would append values to the vector and look for the maximum within that new vector. That lead me to posts suggesting that was a more pythonic than R way of doing things.

Can anyone help? I imagine this is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to get the `cummax` of 'value', check whether it is equal to 'value'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(record = c('no', 'yes')[(value == cummax(value)) + 1])

# A tibble: 10 x 3
#    time value record
#   <int> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1     1  7.76 yes   
# 2     2  6.26 no    
# 3     3  8.28 yes   
# 4     4  8.24 no    
# 5     5  6.78 no    
# 6     6  2.08 no    
# 7     7  4.46 no    
# 8     8  1.34 no    
# 9     9  3.64 no    
#10    10  9.08 yes
```

Comment: why not `df %>% mutate(record = if_else(value == cummax(value), "yes", "no"))`? worries about floating point?

Comment: Perfect, cummax is what i was after.